# Estimating prevalence in a subpopulation

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation

In my problem, each individual can be categorized on two binary dimensions, A and B (each individual can be A or not-A, and B or not-B).  It is not known whether there is some dependency between A and B.

I have picked a random sample (about 15 % of the population).  I know which individuals in the sample are A and which are not-A (there are much more not-As than As).  I also know which A-individuals in the sample are B and which are not-B.  For this question, please assume that it is impractical to determine how not-A individuals in the sample fare on the B dimension.

I know I can estimate a confidence interval for the prevalence of A in the population using for example the Wilson score method.

Can I somehow estimate a confidence interval for the prevalence of B in the subpopulation of individuals that have the A property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same method, but your confidence interval may be wider as you have a smaller sample size.